# I am revising a Hotel Reservation System in Our School and my problem is i'm having a hard time showing the output of my prices

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from tblpv where refID = :refID";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':refID', $refID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$norooms = 0;
$extrabed = 0;

foreach ($results as $result) {
  $norooms += $result->norooms;
  $extrabed += $result->extrabed;
}
```

This is my html form not complete only example

```
    <li>Number of Rooms: <b><?php echo $norooms ?></b></li>
    <li>Number of Extra Bed: <b><?php echo $extrabed ?></b></li>
```

I still can't have my answers shown. I want to know why and how.

[The Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqsIu.png)
[The Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNQjH.png)

EDIT 1
My result from the first answer.
[image]

1
[image]
2
[image]
3
[image]
4
[image]
5
[image]
6
[image]
7
[image]
8
[image]
9
[image]
10
[image]
11
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what i did, is it right? There's no changes at all sorry i think i lack of logical thinking.
[image]

and this is the result of Number of rooms and Number of extra bed
[image]

this is what i got

Comment: Your HTML is commented out. `-->` is how one closes HTML comments, not `--!>`

Comment: sorry that was a mistake.

Ita actually looks like this
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul>
      
        <li>Number of Rooms: <b><?php echo $norooms ?></b></li>
        <li>Number of Extra Bed: <b><?php echo $extrabed ?></b></li>
        <li>Arrival: <b><?php echo date_format($adn, 'M d, Y'); ?></b></li>
        <li>Departure: <b><?php echo date_format($ddn, 'M d, Y'); ?></b></li>
        <li>Length of stay: <b><?php echo $lengthofstay->format('%r%a'); ?></b></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

Comment: This is unreadable in comment. You still can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60258516/edit) your question to add relevant informations

Comment: Is that code in the same page than the one that does the SQL query ? Are you getting any warning/error message ?

Comment: yes. It's only on one form. no error it's just that no computed value is showing up for my norooms and extrabed

Comment: Please add the line print_r($results); before the foreach and add the result into your question.

Comment: wait let me post my whole code if i can, its my first time using stack so please bare with me

Comment: I'd do the sum in MySql by using the appropriate functions and not by php. It's way too unefficient compared to the mysql solution.

Comment: btw, where is the norooms field defined in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and tell us the output:

```
$refID = '7425901624';

$sql = "SELECT SUM(extrabed) as extrabed, COUNT(id) as norooms from tblpv where refID = :refID";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':refID', $refID);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "Result: "; print_r( $results ); echo "<br />";
echo "Extrabed: " . $results['extrabed'] . "<br />";
echo "Norooms: " . $results['norooms'] . "<br />";
```

Comment: i tried it already, but still im not getting any result. what might be the problem? Is it because i set the value of $norooms and $extrabed =0? and when i remove it nothing's showing up. I wanna know the logic of getting the value from the database and show it on the website form like an invoice. E.g: TOTAL NUMBER OF BEDS: $10

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of the database and your full code?

Comment: okay, just a moment. it tells to add more text because the code is too long and in what way i can send my db?

Comment: You can take a screenshot of it and add it into your question.

Comment: i already attached the database and the website. Im really having trouble with the full code because you need to make a description. And i can't really express my full thought about the code. do you want a screenshot too?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please try it out and tell me what you get on your display.

Comment: i already attached the answer. sorry I can't really get the answer.

Comment: @user12911172 , please post the image of your result from this suggestion into your question instead of appending it into the person's original answer.

Comment: Please try my example and add a screenshot of it in your question at the top. There must be at least `Result:`, `Extrabed:` and so on. Where is your php code stored? Can you post a screenshot of your full code?

Comment: I already attached the codes and answer of the code that you've given me, as you can see at the top right corner, that's the answer that i got.

Comment: Thats looking good. Now you have your two numbers in `$results['extrabed']`and `$results['norooms']`. Replace `$extrabed` and `$norooms` in your `HTML` with them. Dont forget to delete the line `$refID = '7425901624'`. Now try to open you page with `?refID=7425901624`

Comment: can you check what i did? thanks im really not sure of that. Im getting inappropriate result.

Comment: @user12911172 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNQjH.png) In tblpv, norooms column does not exits. why are you   getting of this column $result->norooms; ?

Comment: I think `norooms` represent be the `number of rooms`? What do you get now behind `Number of Rooms` and behind `Number of Extra Bed`?

Comment: http://localhost/uehotelier3v6/confirm-reservation?refID=9098537487&&checkIn=2020-02-21&&checkOut=2020-02-22. This is my url.

Comment: please see my question above i attached there the result.

Comment: What result do you get with this URL: http://localhost/uehotelier3v6/confirm-reservation?refID=7425901624&checkIn=2020-02-21&checkOut=2020-02-22

Comment: i got 1 for number of rooms and 0 for extrabed, please look at it above.